# Need further explanation on Invariant Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, invariant-theory

I'm leaning about invariant subspaces, and the topic seems to be too hard for me to comprehend. Reading the topic off Wikipedia, the following explanation is given about matrix representations of invariant subspaces:

> Over a finite dimensional vector space every linear transformation T : V → V can be represented by a matrix once a basis of V has been chosen.
>
> Suppose now W is a T invariant subspace. Pick a basis C = {v1, ..., vk} of W and complete it to a basis B of V. Then, with respect to this basis, the matrix representation of T takes the form:
>
> \begin{bmatrix}T_{11}&T_{12}\\0&T_{22}\end{bmatrix}

I don't really understand why this is the matrix, how can they say with certainty that this is the representation when we don't know anything about the $T$ (specifically, the dimension of the span of $V$).

They go further, explaining that T can be represented as an operator matrix

> Viewing T as an operator matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}T_{11}&T_{12}\\T_{21}&T_{22}\end{bmatrix}:\begin{matrix}W\\\oplus \\W'\end{matrix} \rightarrow \begin{matrix}W\\\oplus \\W'\end{matrix}
$$

I've never seen this kind of representation before. Can anyone provide an alternative explanation? If we choose a basis for W (C) and a basis for V (B), then with respect to the basis $B ∪ C$ (which is just B), how will our matrix look?

Wouldn't it just be the matrix representation of $[T]_B$?

Comment: If $T: X\rightarrow X$ is a linear transformation on the vector space $X$, then $M\subset X$ is an invariant subspace of $T$ if $TM\subseteq M$. For example, an eigenspace of $T$ is an invariant subspace, which is a big part of the motivation for looking at such things.

Comment: Let’s start with basics: do you understand block matrix notation? Do you understand the relationship between the columns of a transformation matrix and the basis vectors used to construct it? Do you understand that the coordinates of a vector are the unique coefficients in the linear combination of basis vectors that produce it?

Comment: I understand block matrix notation, I understand the relationship between the columns of a transformation matrix and the basis and I understand that coordinates of a vector are unique to the basis on which the transformation is done. After some searching I did manage to understand it, but I'm still not familiar with the notation on the right of the block matrix, and don't understand what it means.